# Angular, cargar el LocalStorage

Tags: angular, ionic

Buen día

estoy en la tarea de aprender desarrollo en Ionic 4 con angular pero me encuentro con pequeñas dificultades

tengo la siguiente funcion en un componente llamado login.page.ts

```
async login(){
const valido = await this.serviceapiservice.login(this.userData);
if(valido){
  this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home', {animated:true});
}
```

}

en el service-api.service.ts tengo:

```
login(credentials) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    return new Promise(resolve =>{
      this.http.post(apiUrl+'login', JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers})
      .subscribe(resp =>{
        if(resp['status']){
          this.guardarToken(resp);
          resolve(true);
        }else{
          console.log('falle');
          resolve(false);
        }
      });
    });
  }
  async guardarToken(token){
    this.token = token;
    await this.storage.set('token',token);
  }
```

lo que hace es obtener los datos de un formulario de login y los guarda en un json "userData" que lo envía a un service para su conexión y validación a través de una ApiRest, al tener una respuesta afirmativa recibe un json con atributo "true" y con toda la data que pueda traer y lo almacena en el Storage. y ahi viene el problema, al hacer el router que sirve para ir a otro componente, como el "home" no logra leer los datos almacenados en el storage, a pesar que ahí están, tengo que hacer que la pagina actualice y recien lee los datos, mi pregunta es si hay manera de que el componente home lea los datos almacenados si tener que refrescar la pagina manualmente?

EDITO:

hay un componente llamado app.component.ts que básicamente es el menú lateral de la aplicación donde quiero que se muestre los datos, llamo a este componente desde los demás componentes para tener siempre el menú lateral, aqui es donde intento cargar el Storage de la siguiente manera.

```
  token : any;
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private router: Router,
    private pushService: PushService,
    private storage: Storage
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
    this.sesionActivate();
  }
  ngOnInit() { }

  async sesionActivate(){
    const token = await this.storage.get('token');
    if(token){
      this.token = token;
      console.log(this.token['data']);
    }
  }
```

y en el html solo llamo a this.token

```
//codigo del menu lateral
//item
<div class="name">
 {{ token?.data.name }}
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @ragnamex, la verdad es que habría que ver parte del código en el componente "Home" y como este está manejando el localstorage.

Probablemente lo que te hace falta es añadir "guards" a tus rutas de angular. 
Estos "guards" se encargarían de preparar todo lo necesario para poder acceder a una ruta. Por ejemplo, los métodos "canActivated" o "canDeactivated" de cada ruta pueden usarse para este propósito.

Pero sin un ejemplo del código de lectura del localStorage, es casi imposible acertar a tu pregunta. Podrías actualizar el contenido de tu pregunta y añadirlo ?

Comment: Ya lo edite estimado, ojala puedas ayudarme

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en que en el componente `login` estás usando directamente `localStorage` y en tu componente `home` usas el plugin de @ionic/storage. Este plugin decide por si mismo donde guardar los datos, puede que lo guarde en `localStorage`, en `Web SQL` o en `IndexedDB`. Mi recomendación, y tal vez la solución, es que uses en ambos casos el plugin de `Storage`

Comment: @Ilsanchez Hola si, lo que pasa es que estaba probando inicialmente con localStorage, pero al ver que no funcionaba estaba probando con el plugin de ionic, pero en ningunos de los casos logré que funcionara, acabo de editarlo como está actualmente. gracias

Comment: Una opción que se me ocurre es que esperes hasta que esté guardado el token. Por ejemplo en tu servicio: `this.guardarToken(respuesta).then(()=> resolve (true));` o con `async/await`: `await this.guardarToken(resp); resolve(true);`

Comment: lo acabo de probar, aun asi no cambia el resultado, quisas le pueda dar acceso al repositorio

Comment: De acuerdo, tal vez estemos mirando donde no deberiamos. Mi usuario en github es KubaseHxC

Comment: @Ilsanchez te añadi al proyecto, estaba intentado hacer con emitter para mandar las variables

Comment: Te he hecho una PR @ragnamex, echa un vistazo a  tu github

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude solucionar ello gracias tu ayuda!